# Let $w<x$ be integers with $x^2-w^2$ beeing a square. Which condition they must satisfy for a $y$ to exist with $y^2-x^2$, $y^2-w^2$ being squares?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

Let $(w,x)$ be two integers with $x^2-w^2$ beeing a perfect square. One simple example is $(w,x)=(4,5)$, since $5^2-4^2=9=\square_1=3^2$.

In this case we cannot find a third integer $y$ which satisfies that the differences $y^2-x^2=\square_2$ and $y^2-w^2=\square_3$ are again perfect squares.

A working example would be $(w,x)=(264,520)$ or $(w,x)=(264,561)$, since in both cases an integer $y=1105$ satisfies $y^2-x^2$ and $y^2-w^2$ beeing squares.

**My question:**
Does there exist a condition on $w,x$ that I may use to quickly check, whether such a third integer $y$ exist? It is quite sufficient (and very helpful) for me if this condition predicts/implies that for given $w,x$ there can be no such $y$.

It would be great, if we could determine this $y$ directly at the same time (although I guess it is almost impossible to obtain $y$ directly without bruteforce).

**What I investigated so far:**
I searched in various approaches to extract such a condition. For example I found in the [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/abs/2952-cycles/67CFF892AEEC2685C6B3D222F228A752) entitled "Cycles" by R. C. Lyness a condition that produces cycles. For example I could generate:

```
[[697.   153.   185.   104.   672.   680.  ]
 [697.   705.3  680.   187.2  153.   107.87]
 [697.   491.4  107.87 479.42 705.3  852.81]
 [697.   842.78 852.81 130.43 491.4  473.78]
 [697.   672.   473.78 822.22 842.78 185.  ]
 [697.   153.   185.   104.   672.   680.  ]]
```

But it seems not to give me a condition that enables me to check whether for two given integers $w<x$ such a third integer $y$ exist. My code for producing Lyness Cycles is given below:

```
def get_6tuple(tp:list[float]) -> list[float]:
    w = tp[0]
    x = tp[1]
    y = tp[2]
    return [y,w,x,sqrt(x**2-w**2),sqrt(y**2-x**2),sqrt(y**2-w**2)]

def rotate_np(tuple:np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    p = tuple[0]
    v = tuple[4]
    w = tuple[5]
    return [p, np.float(p*w/v), w, np.float(tuple[2]*w/v), tuple[1], np.float(p*tuple[3]/v)]

def generate_cycle_np(triple:np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    res = np.empty((6,6), dtype=np.float)
    tuple = np.array(get_6tuple(triple), dtype=np.float)
    for i in range (0,6):
        res[i]=tuple
        tuple = rotate_np(tuple)
    return res

print(np.array_str(generate_cycle_np([153, 185, 697]), precision=2, suppress_small=True))
```

Comment: I edited one of my answers to show new developments. I hope you like them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For there to be two solutions, the variable $\space y\space$ must have two distinct prime factors of the form
$\space 4x+1, x\in\mathbb{N}.\quad$
There will be
$\space 2^{f-1}\space$
primitive solutions (those with no common divisors)  where
$\space f\space $ is the number of such factors. For example,
$\space 65=5\times13\space$ so there are
$\space 2^{2-1}=2\space $ such solutions. There "can" be
$\space 3\space$ solutions but one of those will be imprimitive like your
$\space 264,520 \space$
where there are non-primitive solutions for each:
$\space(264,448,520)=8\times (33,56,65)\space $ and
$\space(520,576,776)=8\times (65,72,97).\qquad $

To "know" there will be $\space 3\space$ solutions we must also "know" there will be $\space 4\space$ solutions. For example,
$\space 1105=5\times13\times 17\space$ so there are $\space 2^{3-1}=4\space$ solutions.
Note: Wolfram Alpha can find these factors as fast as you can type them
[here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+1105).
Wolfram Alpha can also provide a [list of primes in a defined range](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=primes+900+to1000) and any product and/or power of these where $\space p=4x+1\space$ is a valid $\space y$-value for your purposes.

To find these solutions, we begin with Euclid's formula for generating triples $\space(A,B,C)\space$ where $\space A^2+B^2=C^2.\quad$
Note: ($y=C\space$ in your case.)
$$ A=m^2-k^2,\quad B=2mk,\quad C=m^2+k^2$$
If we solve the $\space C$-function for $\space k\space$ and test a defined range of $\space m$-values, those that yield integers are for valid $\space (m,k)\space$ solutions in the formula.

$$C=m^2+k^2\implies k=\sqrt{C-m^2}\\
  \qquad\text{for}\qquad \bigg\lfloor\frac{ 1+\sqrt{2C-1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor \le m \le \big\lfloor\sqrt{C-1}\big\rfloor$$
The lower limit ensures $m>k$ and the upper limit ensures $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
$$C=1105\implies \bigg\lfloor\frac{ 1+\sqrt{2210-1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor=24 \le m \le \big\lfloor\sqrt{1105-1}\big\rfloor=33\quad \\
\text{and we find} \quad m\in\{24,31,32,33\}\Rightarrow
 k\in\{23,12,9,4\}\\$$
$$f(24,23)=(47,1104,1105)\quad
f(31,12)=(817,744,1105)\\ 
f(32,9)=(943,576,1105)\quad  
f(33,4)=(1073,264,1105)\quad $$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134231/discussion-on-answer-by-poetasis-let-wx-be-integers-with-x2-w2-beeing-a-s).

Answer (score 2):

I can easily show you that a finite search is enough.

Notice that for positive integers $b>a$, we have $b^2-a^2\geq (a+1)^2-a^2 =2a+1$.

Moreover, $b^2-a^2 \geq b^2-(b-1)^2 =2b-1$.

So if you give me $x$ and want me to determine whether there exist $t>s$ such that $t^2-x^2=s^2$, which is equivalent to $t^2 -s^2 =x^2$, I know that $s$ cannot be bigger than $\frac{x^2 -1}{2}$ and that $t$ cannot be bigger than $\frac{x^2 +1}{2}$. $\blacksquare$

I will leave you to figure out whether there are more efficient algorithms for your purpose.

$\\$

**One suggestion**:

Suppose you give me $x,w$ and you need me to find $y$ such that $x^2 +a^2 =w^2 +b^2 =y^2 $.

All Pythagorean triples are of the form $(t^2-s^2, 2st, t^2+s^2)$.

The idea would then be to solve $x=t^2-s^2$ or $x=2st$, and then do the same for $w$. This gives you every relevant Pythagorean triple.

Both possibilities $x=2st$ and $x=t^2-s^2=(t-s)(t+s)$ involve nothing more than factorising $x$.

Maybe to make the algorithm even more efficient, you can eliminate some cases based on $\mod{4}$ or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for this first hint/solution. Indeed it would be really great to have a condition that verifies the existence of $y$ using "one shot" (without searching/itearting or recursion).  Your approach, however, is a very good start.

Comment: I'm afraid that some brute force might be needed. The "neatest" approach will probably, at the bare minimum, involve finding the prime factors of $x$ and $w$, which requires checking every prime up to a certain size.

Comment: In this case it would be really great to have a verifier that is as most fast/efficient as possible.

Comment: If brute force is the only way, then we can consider having a very large prime table at hand. Our implementation incorporates a really large prime table.

Comment: Added a suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Edit, too big for a comment.

The triples found where
$\space x^2-y^2, y^2-x^2, y^2-w^2\space$
are all squares depends on the software used to search. In one version, I generated sets of two values and, if their square difference was a square, I tested to see if both values were part of a triple with the same $\space y$-value. We have seen those results.

In another test, I found that
$\space x-y=1\space$ in all cases, e.g.

\begin{align*}
d^2=x^2-y^2\space &\qquad\qquad(w,x,y)\\
d=27720\space&(384199200,384199201,543339720)\\
d=92672\space&(4294049816,4294049817,6072703488)\\
d=185600\space&(17223654596,17223654597,24357925924)\\
d=188160\space &(17702074940,17702074941,25034514463)\\
d=198144\space &(19630499812,19630499813,27761719071)\\
\end{align*}

Finally, I used a formula I developed in $\space 2009 \space$ which generates only the subset of triples where
$\space GCD(A,B,C)\space$ is an odd square. This includes all primitives and some imprimitives that are
$\space 9, 25, 49, 81, \cdots$ multiples of primitives.
\begin{align*}
A&=&(2n-1)^2+  & 2(2n-1)k \\ 
B&=&           & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2 \\ 
C&=&(2n-1)^2+  & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2 \\
\end{align*}

Here is a sample of the sets within the subset that it produces.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
Set_n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5\\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61\\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65&39,80,89\\ \hline
Set_3& 35,12,37& 45,28,53& 55,48,73&65,72,97& 75,100,125 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137&119,120,169\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

In a new program, I looped values of
$\space(n,k)\space$ and tested those to see if
$\space\sqrt{\mid B^2-A^2\mid}\space$ was an integer. This automatically makes
$\space C^2-B^2=A^2\space\text{and}\space C^2-A^2=B^2.\quad$ Here is a sample of what it finds with user direction $\space 5\space$ sets and $\space 2\space$  triples per set.

\begin{align*}
d^2=\mid x^2-y^2\mid \,&\quad F(n,k)=(w,x,y)\\
d=94930419\, & F(1,6889)=(13779,94930420,94930421)\\
d=94957979\, & F(1,6890)=(13781,94957980,94957981)\\
d=948954599\, & F(2,21781)=(130695,948954608,948954617)\\
d=950610791\, & F(2,21800)=(130809,950610800,950610809)\\
d=2148466763\, & F(3,32773)=(327755,2148466788,2148466813)\\
d=2148728975\, & F(3,32775)=(327775,2148729000,2148729025)\\
d=4295254539\, & F(4,46339)=(648795,4295254588,4295254637)\\
d=4295439911\, & F(4,46340)=(648809,4295439960,4295440009)\\
d=6098386239\, & F(5,55215)=(993951,6098386320,6098386401)\\
d=6101478923\, & F(5,55229)=(994203,6101479004,6101479085)\\
\end{align*}

Here is the code that yielded these data.

```
110 rem Find w,x,y diff perfect squares
120 print "Enter lowest Set number  "; : input l0
130 print "Enter highest Set number "; : input n9
140 print "Number of Triples per Set  "; : input c9
150 k9 = 10000000
160 print "d^2=\mid x^2-y^2\mid \,&\quad F(n,k)=(w,x,y)\\"
170 for n1 = l0 to n9
180      c1 = 0
190   for k1 = 1 to k9
200     w1 = (2*n1-1)^2+2*(2*n1-1)*k1
210     x1 = 2*(2*n1-1)*k1+2*k1^2
220     d1 = sqr(abs(w1^2-x1^2))
230     if d1 = int(d1)
240       y1 = (2*n1-1)^2+2*(2*n1-1)*k1+2*k1^2
250       print "d=" str$(d1)"\, & ";
260       print "F(" str$(n1)"," str$(k1)")=";
270       print "(" str$(w1)"," str$(x1)"," str$(y1)")\\"
280       c1 = c1+1
290       if c1 = c9
300         k1 = k9
310       endif
320     endif
330   next k1
340 next n1
```

Comment: Thank you for this update. Question: We get a subset of the triples -- all primitive ones -- right? If so, we could easily generate all non-primitives by multiplication.

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow Yes, we can get an imprimitive by multiplying all three terms of a primitive by the same multiple greater than 1. By the way, half of all triples have $\space w>x.\space$ Note the operator in my examples.

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow  Euclid’s formula
$\space  A=m^2-k^2,\space B=2mk,\space C=m^2+k^2\space $ 
generates trivials like 
$f(1,1)=(0,2,2)$ and doubles, square multiples, and doubles of square multiples of triples like these:

$$f(3,1)=(8,6,10)=2\times (3,4,5)\\ 
f(4,2)=(12,16,20)=2^2\times (3,4,5)\\ 
f(6,3)=(27,36,45)=3^2\times (3,4,5)\\ 
\quad f(6,2)=(32,24,40)=2\times2^2\times(3,4,5)$$

My formula generates only the odd square multiples like
$$f(2,3)=(27,36,45)=3^2\times (3,4,5)$$
In Euclid’s formula
$\space m=2n-1+k.$

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow  I encourage you to explore the output of this program. If you prefer Python, so be it, but this is very fast code, even in BASIC as shown here. Particularly fascinating is that all members of 
$\space Set_1\quad 6889\space$ 
and above are valid triples, as are the first members of all sets 
$\space 8193\space$ 
and above with only $\space28\space$ triples in between.  My email is poetasis@gmail.com. Let me know what you find.

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow Correction. With higher limits there a more midrange triples but nothing like the apparently unlimited triples at the extremes $6889$ and $8193.$

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow  I made edits which make the code look as far as needed into each set to reveal any number of specified members. You might just consider downloading free Chipmunk basic and running "this" code.

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow  I tried the first three  triples in your list but I could not figure out how to get a square out of any of the differences. I believe the triples are invalid because, starting with the first one,
$\quad d=1562296.95836131\quad f(600,52)=(1562297,130104,1567705)\quad $as opposed to $\quad d=62627172846\quad F(600,176360)=(424348881,62628610480,62630048081)\quad$ which is the first one my program reveals in $\space Set_{600}.\quad$ Also, you are generating only one triple per set instead of what I infer to be the four specified by input. Let me know what you find.

Comment: Thanks for checking. There obviously is a flaw in my code and I am trying to fix it and provide a link with the corrected Python notebook. Which input values `l0`, `n9` and `c9` did you use while running your code?

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow  For the examples shown in the answer above, the user entry part looked like this.

\begin{align*}
&\text{ >run }\\
&\text{ Enter lowest Set number  ? 1 }\\
&\text{ Enter highest Set number ? 5 }\\
&\text{ Number of Triples per Set  ? 2 }\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Euler has given solution, as re-produced in

Tito Piezas web site. His web site is:

"Collection of algebraic identities".

$y^2-w^2=q^2$

$x^2-w^2=r^2$

$x^2-y^2=p^2$

$(x,y,z)=(434657,420968,150568)$

$(p,q,r)=(108225,393120,407745)$

Comment: I am searching for a general condition in terms of $w$ and $x$.

Comment: Euler imposed the condition, (pqrs) & [(p^2-q^2)(r^2-s^2)] both squares.  He took (p,q,r,s)=(4,9,49,81). He then took (a,b,c,d)=[(pr+qs),(ps-qr),(pr-qs),(ps+qr)].  After which he got (x,y,w)=[(1/2(a^2+b^2),1/2(a^2-b^2),1/2(c^2-d^2)]. Thus we have, (x,y,w)=(434657,420968,150568). And (p,q,r)=(108225,393120,407745). (p,q,r) are related as: {p^2+q^2=r^2].